# Could not find Linked Service linked_service; the linked service does not exist or is not published

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to connect to a storage account in a Scala notebook via Synapse. I am following instructions as outlined from this documentation: https://www.drware.com/using-msi-to-authenticate-on-a-synapse-spark-notebook-while-querying-the-storage-2/

My code looks like this:

```
val sc = spark.sparkContext
spark.conf.set("spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName", linked_service)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type", "com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider") 

val config_load_path = s"abfss://$storage_container_name@$storage_account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/"

val df_config = mssparkutils.fs.ls(config_load_path)
```

But for some reason, the error that I keep getting is:

> "Could not find Linked Service linked_service; the linked service does
> not exist or is not published."

What am I doing wrong? I am able to connect to this linked service if I switch to pySpark and use spark.read, so it's not as if I set up the linked service incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my Azure auth tokens may have expired, so it could not access the storage account. In any case, you will need to refresh the page or reopen your browser entirely.